# How to render a Meteor Template from Collection of Template names?

Tags: meteor

I have three simple Templates in Meteor, and a Collection on the server with any combination of their names. I want to be able to render these templates dynamically based on which of their names are in the Collection.

Currently I am trying to accomplish this by using the client to subscribe to the Collection, and access the names through a template function. Unfortunately, if I try to run *">"* on the names, Meteor attempts to render the variable name instead of the Template pointed to by its value.

So instead of rendering the html in *template1*, *template2*, and *template3*, the output is merely their names on the page: "template1 template2 template3".

Here is the code I've been using, I hope there's a way to solve my issue without having to run Meteor.render manually.

Server js:

```
TemplatesToRender = new Meteor.Collection("templatesToRender");

TemplatesToRender.insert({templateName: "template3"});
TemplatesToRender.insert({templateName: "template2"});
```

Client html:

```
<body>
    {{#each templatesToRender}}
        {{> templateName}}           // meteor trying to render a template
                                     // called "templateName" instead of the 
                                     // variable inside templateName.
    {{/each}}
</body>

<template name="template1">
    <span>Template 1</span>
</template>

<template name="template2">
    <span>Template 2</span>
</template>

<template name="template3">
    <span>Template 3</span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a `render` helper:

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('render', function(name, options) {
   if (Template[name])
     return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[name]());
 });
```

And use it with

```
{{render templateName}}
```

Comment: The problem here is memory management, he is re generating the template over and over again because you call the `Template[name]()` function.  This method is nice, but dont remove the template properly when replaced. I tester this, and you after inserting and removing a few tousand fivs, you get 50 mb of memory stacking up!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this

in your html

```
<body>

    {{> templateToRender}}

</body>

<template name="templateToRender">

    {{! use below to detect which template to render}}

    {{#if templateName "template1"}}
        {{> template1}}
    {{/if}}

    {{#if templateName "template2"}}
        {{> template3}}
    {{/if}}

    {{#if templateName "template3"}}
        {{> template3}}
    {{/if}}

</template

<template name="template1">

    <p>this is template1</p>

</template>

<template name="template2">

    <p>this is template2</p>

</template>

<template name="template3">

    <p>this is template3</p>

</template>
```

in your script

```
Template.templateToRender.templateName = (which) ->
    # if user have a field like templateName you can do things like
    tmplName = Meteor.user().templateName
    # Session.equals will cause a template render if condition is true.
    Session.equals which, tmplName
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor 1.0 just came out today, and I just want to update this for 2014 :)

https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=template [data=data] }}
```

Sample Usage:

```
{{#each kitten}}
   {{> Template.dynamic template=kitten_type data=this }}
{{/each}}
```